# Playing Amazon Prime Videos in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, html5, video-streaming

I installed widevine plugin by copying its .so files ( libwidevinecdmadapter.so, libwidevinecdm.so ) to /usr/lib/chromium-browser in my Ubuntu 16.04. I see widevine in chrome://components/ as well. I had changed the useragent string to Chrome Linux's useragent string. Yet Prime video shows this error when I try to play a video.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It2v3.png)

Can I resolve this problem and play videos somehow?

Comment: I had the same problem, and found that all my old tricks would not work. I was finally able to play video on the latest firefox. You have to 'enable drm', which shows up as a yellow banner when you load amazon video in firefox. Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't enable anything to make it run in Firefox. It was running by default.